# Is proving completeness of a logic system the same as showing a set of operators is complete?

Tags: logic, definition, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

In propositional logic I believe we aim to show the system is "correct" by showing it is both sound and complete.

For the completeness piece is this the same as showing that the Boolean operator set $\Omega$ is functionally complete, i.e. Post's Lattice/Theorem? Or is this a different concept and completeness is proved some other way?

Comment: No; the two are not the same. That regarding boolean operators is [Functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness), also called *expressive adequacy* (contrasted to : [Semantic completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)#Semantic_completeness)).

Comment: See [Formal system based on the Sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke#Formal_system_based_on_the_Sheffer_stroke) : the so-called Sheffer stroke (also called nand ("not and")) is a single connective that is functionally complete for classical prop calculus. A sound and complete proof system based on it (see link) needs one single axiom and one rule of inference. If we remove the axiom, what we get is a system that is still functionally complete but obviously not (semantiocally) complete (it cannot prove anything).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That example made it click for me, thank you

Comment: (only part I don't get is why one rule and one axiom is needed when ND has no axioms for example)

Comment: I've never seen it, but we may imagine an ND calculus based on Sheffer stroke, with a couple of rules (as usual) : one for introducing the connective and one for eliminating it. Now, if we remove one of the rules, what we get will be (semantically) incomplete.

Comment: A functional not-complete system is semantically complete ? Yes and no: it can prove **all** tautologies expressible in the language but obviously, if there are some tautologies that are not expressible, it cannot prove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the roles played by the *language* (and in particular the set of connectives) and the *proof system*.

When we say that a language is complete in some sense - e.g. that the usual set of Boolean operations is functionally complete - what we mean is that it can **describe a lot of things**. By contrast, when we say that a proof system is complete (and sound) for a given language *(with respect to a notion of semantics)*, we mean that it can **prove all the things expressible in that language which it should (and none that it shouldn't)** *(where "should(n't)" is understood via the semantics)*.

Note that these are completely different tasks. In particular, if I have a really really weak language, in some sense it's *easier* to construct a complete proof system for it, since there are fewer things it needs to prove (and fewer things it needs not to prove)!

Comment: So when we show a system is complete and sound, the fact that the operators may be functionally complete is just another helpful property to have? i.e. it's just a separate consideration?

Comment: @user525966 Yes, it's completely irrelevant to the proof system's soundness/completeness.

Comment: Even so I don't fully understand the difference between a proof system and a language of expression. "Systems don’t express Boolean functions, they prove things." But don't we need the language/functional in order to prove things? Otherwise what would we even write?

Comment: (also, when you say "sound with respect to semantics"... what else can something be sound to? Is "semantics" not implied or are there alternative options?)

Comment: @user525966 Re: your second question, my point is that we need to choose *some* notion of semantics to talk about truth - but we have options. A proof system may be sound/complete with respect to one semantics but not another; e.g. the usual proof system is unsound with respect to any of the various [intuitionistic semanticses (semantices?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionism).

Comment: @user525966 Re: your first comment, true - but that's not relevant. Of course we need a language in order to even think about a proof system *for* that language, but that doesn't mean that every property of the language is *relevant to* every property of the proof system. Think about it this way *(ignore the informality)*: "English has a word for every color" is completely unrelated to "I know every true English statement about colors:" the latter asserts completeness *of my knowledge*, the former asserts completeness *of the language* in a certain sense, and neither is required for the other.

Comment: So if I made a system that was complete and sound it may still be inferior to some other system that is also complete and sound  but happens to be functionally complete as well? Are there other considerations to note outside of semantic soundness/completeness and functional completeness?

Comment: @user525966 Yes, but you need to distinguish between the *proof system* and the *logical language* more. Instead, say "if I made a proof system that was complete and sound with respect to some language $L$ it may still be inferior to some other proof system that is also complete and sound with respect to a stronger language $L'$ (e.g. maybe $L'$ is functionally complete but $L$ isn't)." That is, it's the language, not the proof system, which is (or isn't) functionally complete. *(Aside: there is such a thing as a ["nonlogical language"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic).)*

Comment: So when we talk about syntax and semantics these are only part of the proof system and are independent of the logical language?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83107/discussion-between-noah-schweber-and-user525966).

Answer (score 1):

No, these are completely (!) different concepts.

In ease case "complete" means something like "able to do everything we reasonably want". But even the *kind* of things we reasonably want them to do are entirely different between the two situations.

For a proof system what we reasonably want to *prove all logically valid formulas*.

For a set of connectives what we reasonably want is to write down formulas that *express* arbitrary truth functions.

Comment: I guess I don't see the difference between the two. I thought completeness was the concept of being able to write any arbitrary Boolean function (all 2^(2^n) of them)

Comment: @user525966: Yes, that's completeness for a set of connectives. It has nothing to do with completeness of a _proof system_.

Comment: What is the difference? Proving all logically valid formulas for completeness..., I thought we used soundness property to show that we prove only true/valid formulas.

Comment: To elaborate: I thought completeness was the idea that we can prove everything, and then soundness was the idea that everything we can prove is also true. Together, meaning we can prove all true statements and inky those statements.

Comment: @user525966: What's the difference? _Everything_ about it is different, other than the same word being used. You're saying "I thought completeness was this thing" (expressing any Boolean function), then three comments later you're saying "To elaborate, I thought completeness was" something completely different, and _then_ you're saying you don't see any difference between these two entirely separate concepts!? Can you even describe one single thing that **other than the word "complete"** that "expressing every Boolean function" and "proving every valid statement" have _in common_?

Comment: I'm saying if we show that we can construct all Boolean functions and then also show we can only prove true statements, why is this not the idea?

Comment: @user525966: Showing that you can prove only true (I suppose you mean valid) statements is not completeness, but soundness.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that / understand that

Comment: And even if it was the same, which similarity do you see between "showing you can express every Boolean function" and "showing your logical system proves only valid statements"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83067/discussion-between-henning-makholm-and-user525966).

Comment: @user525966 constructing all Boolean functions has nothing to do with the deductive system. A deductive system does not appear anywhere in that concept. Deductive systems could have never existed and that concept would be fine. Whereas soundness/completeness is *about* a deductive system.

Comment: I'm saying I don't see the difference between "expressing all Boolean functions in your system" and the usual definition of completeness (that whatever we can show as valid, we can also prove). I don't see how "expressing all functions" is not satisfying that requirement

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't understand what you're saying there. If we are not able to express all Boolean functions could we still have a sound/complete system?

Comment: @user525966:I honesly don't understand how those two things are even remotely similar to you. Please explain what you find similar between them.

Comment: I just did in my comment above

Comment: @user525966: No you didn't. Please explain JUST ONE SINGLE THING (**other than the word "complete"**) that you find are similar between the idea of a set of connectives being able to express all Boolean functions, and the idea of a deductive system being able to prove all valid formulas in its language.

Comment: Is it possible to have a system that is both complete and sound but not be able to express all Boolean functions?

Comment: If the answer to that question is "no" then that's my point of question

Comment: @user525966 Yes, but that is irrelevant to my point. My point is going the other way. Can we have a notion of expressing every Boolean function without ever mentioning the word “system”? I’m saying yes. That alone means these aren’t the same thing. Systems don’t express Boolean functions, they prove things. A particular system’s *language* expresses Boolean functions.

Comment: @user525966: A **deductive system** is not able to express _any_ Boolean function. That's not what is for -- it's what a logical language (a set of connectives) does. A set of connectives is not the same as a proof system, and a proof system is not the same as a set of connectives.

Comment: @user525966 Even if it were “no”, and there weren’t this issue with system vs langauge, one thing being necessary for another is a pretty far cry from them being the same thing.

Comment: And one can perfectly well have a system that proves all valid statements that can be expressed in its language, but where that language is **not** complete. Just take $\to$ as your only connective and use a basic Hilbert system with S, K, I and Peirce's law. (Or for that matter the $\to$ fragment of classical sequent calculus). The set $\{{\to}\}$ is not complete (since it is truth-preserving), but the proof system _is_ complete.

Comment: @HenningMakholm S, K, I?

Comment: @user525966: $(a\to b\to c)\to(a\to b)\to a \to c$ and $a\to b\to a$ and $a\to a$.